# Byte[] from DB to BitmapImageSource -- One Error After Another

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmap

I am creating a UWP app for the company I work for part of the process is to upload an ID Photo. When the user clicks to upload a picker displays and it loads the image to an Image Element. This works fine, the issue is when the pull an existing record that has a photo attached already. The file is stored as a byte[], the code I use on .Net web apps does not work here. I can not get it to work even after a week of reading post after post on countless sites.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    photo.ID = reader.GetGuid(0);
                                    photo.AttachmentType = reader.GetString(1);
                                    photo.AttachmentSize = reader.GetInt32(2);
                                    photo.Attachment = (byte[])reader.GetValue(3);
                                }
                            }
                            RemoveBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eSql)
        {
            var err = eSql.Message.ToString();
        }

        if (photo.Attachment != null && photo.Attachment.Length > 0)
        {
            //StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            //StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync($"tempImg{photo.AttachmentType}");
            //string path = @"D:\DOT2";
            //string fileName = "tempImg.png";
            //string pathStr = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(photo.Attachment, 0, photo.Attachment.Length);

                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = stream.AsRandomAccessStream())
                {

                    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                    await img.SetSourceAsync(fileStream); //Error Occurs here.
                    CIPhoto.Source = img;
                }

            }

            UploadBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            RemoveBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

The expected result is to convert the byte[] to a BitmapImageSource that i can set to an Image UI Element. I get error after error, currently i get an error saying : 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'. The commented section tells me that i am denied access. I am stuck, please help.

Comment: Why are you using Steam.WriteAsync instead of Steam.Write method?

Comment: Why not just `using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(photo.Attachment, false)) { ... await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);... }`?

Comment: Usually when you want to read the data you just wrote to the stream (it's `MemoryStream` in this case), you should `Seek` it back to beginning: `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` after you `WriteAsync(...)` to it.

Comment: I think the issue was with UWP, I switch the program over to WPF and have had ZERO errors since. Even the image works perfectly. Plus Entity Framework works with WPF but not with UWP for DB Access.